# sessionAffinity based on clientIP is not maintained for a new UDP request after TCP request

Tags: sockets, kubernetes, tcp, udp, openshift

lets say, we have two independent Kubernetes clusters `Cluster 1 & Cluster 2` , Each of them has two replicas of same application Pod. Like `Cluster 1 : Pod A & Pod B` and `Cluster 2 : Pod C & Pod D`. Application code in Pod A(client) wants to connect to any Pod running in cluster 2 via NodePort/Loadbalancer service over TCP protocol where the response would carry a UDP Port stating the client(Pod A) to initiate a new UDP connection on supplied UDP port for further communication.

To summarize the need:

`1.Pod A -> Pod C   over TCP, and response carries a UDP port`

`2.Pod A -> Pod C   over UDP port captured in response`

But here, while making UDP call, the request is going to other Pod i.e., Pod D. SessionAffinity set to clientIP is not helping. I want both TCP and UDP calls to fall on same pod.

Comment: This is more or less a stateful setup. You need to give Pod C a "stable address", e.g. expose each pod with its own unique ip or solve it in some other way. Usually Pods are seen as disposable and Deployments as stateless services. You need the properties from StatefulSet but expose outside the cluster.

Comment: @Jonas In this case, I may have to compromise with dynamic scaling , right ?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Unless you build and Operator that can manage it, but its lots of work.